# gap between sandia hand and robot hand mount

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On both the left and right sides there seems to be about a 1cm gap between the sandia hand "palm" and the r_hand/l_hand part of the robot. Is this correct?
I launched the robot using drcsim-2.0 out of the box with

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas_sandia_hands.launch
```

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1200/gap-between-sandia-hand-and-robot-hand-mount/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That issue was known and is now [ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/119/sandia-hands-offset-from-atlas-wrists).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0